# How to use Material-Ui Typography component colors with Typescript

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I am creating a function where I have to return a color to be set in the typography component.

```js
<Typography color={getStatus(c).color}>
  { getStatus(c).status }
</Typography>
```

Like so:

```js
  const getStatus = (c: MyType):{status: string, color: string} => {
    const errorColor = 'error';
    const primaryColor = 'primary';
    const secondaryColor = 'secondary';

    if (c === ACondition) {
      return { status: 'Draft', color: primaryColor };
    } else if (c === BCondition) {
      return { status: 'Editing', color: primaryColor };
    } else if (c === CCondition) {
      return { status: 'Failed Publish', color: errorColor };
    }

    return { status: 'Published', color: secondaryColor };
  };
```

But this is yelling:
[image]
[image]

And this is `Typography.d.ts`

```js
export interface TypographyTypeMap<P = {}, D extends React.ElementType = 'span'> {
  props: P & {
    align?: PropTypes.Alignment;
    /**
     * The content of the component.
     */
    children?: React.ReactNode;
    color?:
      | 'initial'
      | 'inherit'
      | 'primary'
      | 'secondary'
      | 'textPrimary'
      | 'textSecondary'
      | 'error';
    display?: 'initial' | 'block' | 'inline';
    gutterBottom?: boolean;
    noWrap?: boolean;
    paragraph?: boolean;
    variant?: Variant | 'inherit';
    variantMapping?: Partial<Record<Variant, string>>;
  };
  defaultComponent: D;
  classKey: TypographyClassKey;
}
```

What should I do to avoid that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Typography` component is expecting a string literal of one of the types specified in its `props.color` (e.g. `initial`, `primary`, `secondary`). It will not accept the broad `string` type, because then you could pass it any old string and it would still compile despite not functioning correctly.

You need to explicitly type the return of your `getStatus` function to match it. This could be done like so:

```
const getStatus = (c: MyType):{status: string, color: 'error' | 'primary' | 'secondary'}
```

Or alternatively, you can pull in the prop interface from the library and index it directly:

```
import { TypographyProps } from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

type TypographyColors = Exclude<TypographyProps["color"], undefined>;

const getStatus = (c: MyType):{status: string, color: TypographyColors}
```

This might be more useful if you add further colors from the MUI theme at a later point. The `TypographyColors` type is quite useful to have as a standalone anyway.